# How can I suggest a feature to the Google Android team?

Tags: android

I have been looking for a easy way to add borders to custom made Views (Compounds or whatever), and the only answer I found was that there is no built-in support for that. Instead there are suggestions that you should add Views on top/below the View you want borders on and a bunch of others really messy ways to get borders.

Coming from the .NET-environment that is pretty brutal to have to do ugly workaround and "hacks" to get something as simple as borders.

Thus, I want to suggest that feature to the Android team. I'm not sure how they can have missed it, but it is surely missed =)

So, is there any official way to suggest a feature in the SDK/framework? I have looked around a bit, but can't comment on their blogs, no e-mail addresses as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your suggestion at [google code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: I have done this and they really do pay attention and do stuff with comments and suggestions.

Comment: There is no point in reporting an issue or feature request there. The stuff there is ignored completely.

Answer (score 2):

sorry, 8 years later. At the link below there's a Feedback section with a link to Feature Requests
https://source.android.com/source/community.html

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a Drawable subclass that draws whatever border you want and reports the padding for that border, and sets it as the background of the view you want to have drawn with a border.  Or set it on a FrameLayout to have the border placed around the other views inside of the frame.

Comment: Btw the platform almost always defines borders as 9-patch drawables.

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer. I know about the Drawable approach. I find that very messy to. Why not just include a border property as usual? I think it is just weird they didnt include that support by default. I tried the Drawable approach, didnt get it to work nicely which sort of proves my point: it's messy =(.

Comment: hackbod: yes, I know about that too. Thats, as I see it, one of those "bunch of messy stuff" to do it. To create a 9-patch image for just getting a border? Horrible approach Id say =( Thx for the answer though =)

Comment: What kind of border are you looking for?  If you just want a blah rectangular border, no, there isn't a super-easy way to do that because...  honestly, no real application that looks decent is going to want to do that.  But for actual design borders, it is very easy -- define it as a drawable, either as a 9-patch or a shape.  I'm sorry you had trouble making a 9-patch drawable, but once you understand it, it is really not that hard.  There are a zillion examples of them in the Android resources because pretty much all of the frames and borders and such in the standard UI are built that way.

Comment: Hello =) Why wouldnt that look "decent"? Im guessing it would look like a line around the View, just as one would expect from a border? =)